Controller verification not working/value being read as null when it is not
I am trying to verify that there is pre-existing entry in the row of a data table before updating its value. This is working for all of my functions except for the one present in a modal that should be adding the final values to the current row.
This is the controller for the salido function.
    public function salido($id)
    {
        $entity = $this->biometricosService->where('id', $id)->first();
        debug_to_console('salido');
        if ($entity->salido == null) {
            $data = $this->biometricosService->update($entity);
            return created_responses('data', ['message' =>  'Actualizacion de registro exitosa', 'data' => $data]);
        } else {
            return created_responses('data', ['message' =>  'No puede volver a timbrar para salido', 'code' => 400]);
        }
    }

and the function within a modal that calls it.


salido() {
            try {
                alert('Salir?');

                const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
                const id = localStorage.getItem('id_timbrada');

                axios.patch(`/masterdata/biometricos/salido/${id}`, {
                    salido: currentTime,
                    description: this.inputs.description,
                    location: this.inputs.location,
                    // total: th
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.data.code == 400) {
                            this.$toastr.e(response.data.message);
                        } else {
                        console.log('Timbrada exitosa:', response.data.data);
                        this.$toastr.s(response.data.message);
                        this.$hub.$emit('reload-' + this.tableId);
}
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });

            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error posting data:', error);
            }
        },



As shown I would like the controller to return an error code if an entry has already been made in the salido column of that row which would then be caught by the salido js function and communicated to the user. What is extra baffling about this not working is that I have almost the exact same thing for some of my other functions. Take regreso for example.
public function regreso($id)
    {
        $entity = $this->biometricosService->where('id', $id)->first();
        if ($entity->regreso == null) {
            $data = $this->biometricosService->update($entity);
            return created_responses('data', ['message' =>  'Actualizacion de registro exitosa', 'data' => $data]);
        } else {
            return created_responses('data', ['message' =>  'No puede volver a timbrar para regreso', 'code' => 400]);
        }
    }



regreso() {
            try {
                alert('Regresar?');

                const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
                const id = localStorage.getItem('id_timbrada');

                axios.patch(`/masterdata/biometricos/regreso/${id}`, {
                    regreso: currentTime
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.data.code == 400) {
                            this.$toastr.e(response.data.message);
                        }
                        console.log('Timbrada exitosa:', response.data.data);
                        localStorage.setItem('regreso', response.data.data.regreso)
                        this.$toastr.s(response.data.message);
                        this.$hub.$emit('reload-' + this.tableId);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });

            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error posting data:', error);
            }
        },



The only real differences, as far as I can tell, are that salido posts more than one value, which shouldn't be a problem as I have other working functions that do that, and that salido occurs in a modal while regreso is in my main index. Any help is much appreciated!
